# How to do a "uname -r" for a different kernel?

Tags: linux, kernel-modules

I would like to setup correct kernel module loading. For this reason I am interested in the output of `uname -r` of the custom kernel I compiled and am about to setup.

Since this kernel is of course not already running I have no clue to how I can get the info of `uname -r` for this kernel, as it is yet to be booted and `uname` only outputs the current kernel id.

Is there a way to determine the output of `uname -r` of the kernel I have just compiled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `file` command may be able to extract information out of a vmlinuz file:

```
Linux/x86 Kernel, Setup Version 0x20d, bzImage, Version 4.15.7-1-default ...
```

Comment: yes I was able to find the `uname -r` equivalent output via your answer, explicitly via this `file path/to/bzImage | sed 's/.*version //' | sed 's/ .*//'`

Comment: I assumed that you are capable of filtering the information from the output of find.

Comment: yep, still I thought to add the small comment for convenience, since this way there is maybe less ambiguity. I hoped, thanks!